# Call a method inside a async method in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-async

has just gone through the spring Async process which calls a method with multiple threads based on the configuration. Just wanted to check on the below scenario.
Can I call a method inside an Async method. For example:

```
Class Main{
    @Autowired 
    private B b;

    for(int I=0;i<5;i++){
        b.asyncMethod();//arguments will be passed
    }
}

@Service
Class BImpl implements B{
    @Autowired
    private C c;

    @Asnc
    @Override
    public void asyncMethod(//aruguments){
        c.callDAO();
    }
}

@Repository
Class CImpl implements C{
    @Override
    public void callDAO(){
    //connect to DB and do DML operation with all connection variables as local to this method

    }
}
```

Please do note that there are no class level variables except for logger and a few constants. Just want to understand the pitfalls of the above scenatio and how to overcome them. This works fine in local runs. But not sure how this would behave in an application server with multiple jvms in more than 1 server in a cluster. Any help/pointers would be great.

Comment: When you say "how this would behave", could you give an example of what you would like to happen and what kind of pitfalls you're expecting?

Comment: Hi Christopher..thanks for your reply. 2 things that I want to understand. One - the call to asyncMethod will b asynchronous..but the call to callDAO WILL b synchronous right? Two - how this woulb behave in a cluster. Is there any scenario that would break the flow?